# How to disable flipping of the "up" button on the action bar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, right-to-left

### Background

I've made an "[**app manager**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager)" alternative app, and I wish to add translation for RTL (right to left) languages.

Since I know that as of certain Android version, things got flipped to let words and sentences align correctly, I decided to first switch to such a language and then continue with the translation

### The problem

After switching to an RTL language (Hebrew in my case), I've found out that the action bar's up button has the "<" image flipped horizontally:

[image]

So now it shows ">" instead.

### The question

How do I fix it? It doesn't make sense to see it this way...

Comment: but behind the scenes it's already using an image. besides, I don't want to override the default image.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, you can access that `ActionBar` "up" affordance by calling `Resources.getIdentifier` and `View.findViewById`. After that you could rotate it.

```
    final int upId = getResources().getIdentifier("up", "id", "android");
    final View up = findViewById(upId);
    // Call this to just rotate the icon 180°
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL) {
        up.setRotation(180f);
    }
```

Comment: Why would I want to animate it?

Comment: To flip it over? I added a gif.

Comment: but i don't want to flip it. I want to avoid the flipping. the flipping occurs by itself, since it's an RTL language...

Comment: also, even if I disable the animation, the rest of the code doesn't make it work. :(

Comment: Yes you do want to flip it. What are you talking about? You want it to flip from ">" to "<". Am I missing something here?

Comment: the problem is that setting the OS language to Hebrew will make it from "<" to ">". I want to avoid it. I want to have the normal direction ("<") , without flipping it to ">" .

Comment: Yeah, so rotating ">" `180°` will give you "<".

Comment: isn't there a better way than to animate it? why is it being flipped?

Comment: Also, I've tested your code and it still doesn't work. it works only if I remove the condition, but then it will occur for all other languages...

Comment: BTW, I think that instead of animation , you can also use setRotation(180) and that's it. it's supported from Honeycomb.

Comment: Made an edit using `View.setRotation` and a different direction check. Not really sure about backwards compatibility for layout directions, since `View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL` was introduced in API 17.

Comment: seems to be the correct condition. edit your answer to be just that (or put a new section or something), and I will tick this answer as the correct one (oh and please remove the gif animation).

Comment: Sure, any particular reason you want me to remove the gif?

Comment: since the solution shouldn't include animation... also edit the answer.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want. I thought you wanted me to remove the gif and `View.setLayoutDirection`. I'm getting the impression you only want the condition to be the answer, but I'm not sure why. Since I'm a little confused about what you want, how about you edit the answer instead?

Comment: I still have a problem with this solution. when I choose to search, I see the "up" button again, and again it's flipped... How do I handle this one?

Comment: Really the system should be handling all of this for you. It's obviously not right that just the "up" affordance is flipped, but not the entire `ActionBar`. I couldn't reproduce your problem, so I offered the only other solution I could think of. As far the `SearchView` goes, I don't remember the id you need, but it's all in the framework/base.

Comment: I don't understand. so you mean I should just leave it all flipped as google intended? but it's weird that everything is opposite, and if I would ever wish to add a navigation drawer, it will be on the left instead of on the right (since the home button goes to the right when you change to RTL locale)... about the id, I think it's exactly the same ID as you've written(checked via DDMS), but for some reason I can't change it like you've done on the code. I've even tried to delay the rotation of the view.

Comment: No, [I'm saying this is what the `ActionBar` looks like when it's flipped RTL](http://i.imgur.com/yrezlUM.png) and I don't know why yous isn't.

Comment: this is what I meant by writing "as google intended", but that's actually different from most google apps, and it doesn't work well with the navigation drawer , which is always on the left... i also think it has weird issues with the viewPager's animations (when you have tabs too).

Comment: Then most of Google's apps don't fully support RTL layouts, but Play Newsstand does and that doesn't mean yours should be the same. Also, `DrawerLayout` will automatically switch to the right side if you're using a RTL layout.

Comment: It seems so. maybe i looked at an early work on the navigation drawer. odd. so even google doesn't follow its own guidelines and use them to the fullest. it's weird that google fixed it for newsStand, but didn't set any hebrew handling for the play store and so many other apps it has... ok i guess, i will just set the supportsRtl to true on the manifest and not worry about the action bar anymore. thank you .

Comment: I think I now get the same problem on Toolbar class, yet the code here didn't help (it can't find the "up" button) ... What should be used?

Comment: I got a null on getting "Up" view

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was to let the system use the default theme, and not specify Holo. If you can live with that, the Up button will be oriented correctly. Unfortunately this cannot be done if you use AppCompat of course. 
To make this even more annoying: the flipping of the up button is device specific. It occurs on Samsung devices but not on Google's. The supportsRtl flag is only for API 17 and above, so older Samsung phones cannot be fixed. 
The issue is apparently the Holo implementation on Samsung devices. Be careful with flipping the icon since on Google phones it will be flipped wrong.

See this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68476

Comment: so it's even more complex than what i thought. anyway, in the end i decided to let the OS decide on its own. you will get a +1 though for the effort of what you've written.