# How to get the "up" button used on the Toolbar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, right-to-left, android-toolbar

This is a short question:

I'm trying to force the action bar (used by a Toolbar) to use LTR alignment. I've succeeded making the layout itself use LTR, but not the "up" button (as I've done [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22602453/878126), before [**Toolbar**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) was introduced) .

It seems this view doesn't have an ID, and I think using getChildAt() is too risky.

Can anyone help?

---

### The answer

Here's one way I've found to solve this, based on [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27180584/878126) .

I made it so that it is guarranteed to find only the "up" button, and whatever it does, it will revert back to the previous state it was before.

Here's the code:

```
  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu)
    {
    // <= do the normal stuff of action bar menu preparetions
    if(VERSION.SDK_INT>=VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1&&getResources().getConfiguration().getLayoutDirection()==View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL)
      {
      final ArrayList<View> outViews=new ArrayList<>();
      final CharSequence previousDesc=_toolbar.getNavigationContentDescription();
      for(int id=0;;++id)
        {
        final String uniqueContentDescription=Integer.toString(id);
        _toolbar.findViewsWithText(outViews,uniqueContentDescription,View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);
        if(!outViews.isEmpty())
          continue;
        _toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(uniqueContentDescription);
        _toolbar.findViewsWithText(outViews,uniqueContentDescription,View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);
        if (outViews.isEmpty())
           if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                    throw new RuntimeException(
                            "You should call this function only when the toolbar already has views");
                else
                    break;
        outViews.get(0).setRotation(180f);
        break;
        }
      _toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription(previousDesc);
      }
    //
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

Comment: No, getChildAt() is not risky, as long as you have covered all egde cases.

Comment: But even then, I need to know for sure that it's the correct view. Anyway, is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: You could use reflection and iterate over declared fields and find the field with exact name you are looking for (let's say "mNavButtonView"). This will guarantee you are pointing to right view. But I do not recommend using reflection. You rather go iterating over children and check of their class instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> It seems this view doesn't have an ID

You're right, [the navigation view is created programmatically](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/Toolbar.java#L985) and never sets an id. But you can still find it by using [`View.findViewsWithText`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewsWithText(java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.view.View%3E,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20int)).

`View.findViewsWithText` comes with two flags:

- [`View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_TEXT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#FIND_VIEWS_WITH_TEXT)
- [`View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION)

The navigation view's default content description is **"Navigate up"** or the resource id is `abc_action_bar_up_description` for AppCompat and `action_bar_up_description` for the framework's, but you can easily apply your own using [`Toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html#setNavigationContentDescription(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Here's an example implementation:

```
final Toolbar toolbar = ...;
toolbar.setNavigationContentDescription("up");
setActionBar(toolbar);

final ArrayList<View> outViews = Lists.newArrayList();
toolbar.findViewsWithText(outViews, "up", View.FIND_VIEWS_WITH_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION);

outViews.get(0).setRotation(180f);
```

**Results**

[image: example]

Comment: Nice solution. What does this function do? the docs say "Set a content description for the navigation button if one is present. The content description will be read via screen readers or other accessibility systems to explain the action of the navigation button." . Is it the toast that is shown for action items when you long click them? if so, what will happen to the "up" button? Also, is it always the first view on the list that will be the "up" button? even if there are others that have this value? Or maybe, because you call it long before the menu is inflated, this doesn't matter anyway?

Comment: OK, I've found all of the issues, and I've updated the question to hold the full answer. I do this since your answer is the correct one, only that it misses some special handling. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @androiddeveloper I was mistaken when I said it didn't have a content description by default. Of course it does and I edited my answer accordingly. It's what's shown or spoken when someone who has accessibility services turned on and they long press the it, yeah. `View.findViewsWithText` traverses the view hierarchy of whichever `View` is calling the method. It will find every `View` with the text or content description you supply, depending on the flag. But the content description for the navigation view should already be unique, no need for that loop.

Comment: Since I didn't want to change this value of any view, and I didn't want to find false positives (in case other items have this value), I had to add those operations. This should work on any possible scenario.

Comment: Say, do you know how will I do it with the support actionBar ? The id there isn't available as well...

Comment: BTW, in order to get the support action mode view, you can use "R.id.action_mode_bar" .